# Google Mail blocking emails sent by postfix

Tags: gmail, postfix

I have set up an email server, but I have a problem with sending mails to Gmail.

This is my /var/log/mail.log:

```
Jun  4 20:49:26 jenny postfix/qmgr[6064]: 4CBDB67482: from=<mail@[...]>, size=627, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun  4 20:49:27 jenny postfix/smtp[6077]: 4CBDB67482: to=<[...]@gmail.com>, \
relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.136.26]:25, delay=1.6, \
delays=0.05/0.01/0.73/0.86, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host \
gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.136.26] said: \
550-5.7.1 [84.119.226.45      12] \
Our system has detected that this message is 550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited \
mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, 550-5.7.1 this message has \
been blocked. \
Please visit 550-5.7.1 \
http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131 for 550 5.7.1 \
more information. 19si6596048wju.143 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

Is there any server configuration I can undertake so that Google will find my ip not as spam sending?

Comment: Are you using a shared host? Usually their IPs are blocked, *especially* if they're a free host.

Comment: No, but can there be some problems with reverse DNS? Because my ISP has a DNS entry (<ip>.<isp-hostnam>) for my IP.

Comment: Setup postfix to use an SMTP account, can even use a gmail account for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

- Add SPF to your domain. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework
- Add DKIM to your domain. http://www.dkim.org/
- Check if your IP is on a black list. http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx
- Send plain text email without links.